# Switching between reference and value semantics

Tags: java, hashmap

By default, Java classes have reference semantics; two instances of the same class are considered different even if all their fields of the same values.

Sometimes what you want is value semantics e.g. `String`, `BigInteger`. There is a straightforward standard way to arrange this: override `equals` and `hashCode` to work on the appropriate fields.

What if you want a class that in some contexts exhibits reference semantics and in others value semantics? (I'm thinking here of a class representing an SSA instruction for compiler intermediate code.) A way to achieve this is to compare with `equals` by value and `==` by reference.

But what if you want to store such objects in two different hash tables, one by reference and the other by value? As I understand it, `HashMap` always uses the overridden by-value `equals` and `hashCode` methods if they are present.

Is there a way to tell `HashMap` that in this particular case you want to compare objects by reference?

Comment: Well, if you don't override `equals` or `hashCode` the ***only*** way to compare the objects for a `HashMap` is by *reference*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Right, so 'don't override' is not a solution either. I suppose a more precise phrasing would be: is there any solution easier and more idiomatic than writing my own hash table for one of the cases?

Comment: But I still don't understand why you would want to use a hash table instead of a directed acyclic graph.

Comment: You could wrap your objects in a class with different equality semantics and put those wrappers in the container.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The primary SSA data structure is a directed acyclic graph, but in practice you end up also needing lots of ancillary hash tables for fast lookup of various things.

Comment: @khelwood True. That would have overhead, but say the by-value case is much rarer, then it doesn't matter if that case has overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell HashMap that in this particular case you want to compare objects by reference?

No, but there is [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html):

> This class implements the Map interface with a hash table, using reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys (and values)

However, there are substantial caveats to its use, detailed in the Javadoc.